# Remove common indexes of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some indexes that I need to remove from main array. For example:

```
$removeIndex=array(1,3,6);
$mainArray=array('1'=>'a','2'=>'b','3'=>'c','4'=>'d','5'=>'e','6'=>'f');
```

I want end result like:

```
 $mainArray=array('2'=>'b','4'=>'d','5'=>'e');
```

I know we have `array_slice` function in PHP, which can be run in loop, but I have very huge data and I want to avoid looping here.

Comment: Could try manipulating with [`array_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: mayb use 
foreach($removeIndex as $index){
unset($mainArray[$index])
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps try `array_diff_key`:

```
$removeIndex=array(1,3,6);
$mainArray=array('1'=>'a','2'=>'b','3'=>'c','4'=>'d','5'=>'e','6'=>'f');
$removeIndex = array_flip($removeIndex);//flip turns values into keys
echo '<pre>';
//compute diff between arr1 and arr2, based on key
//returns all elements of arr 1 that are not present in arr2
print_r(array_diff_key($mainArray, $removeIndex));
echo '</pre>';
```

When I tried this, it returned:

```
Array
(
    [2] => b
    [4] => d
    [5] => e
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for without "LOOPING", Thanks

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem There is a time limit, be patient :-)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, waiting to complete time limit, will give you credit for sure in 1 min.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `array_diff_key`, note that in `removeIndex` array you need to make the values as `keys`

```
$removeIndex=array('1' => 0,'3' => 0,'6' => 0);
$mainArray=array('1'=>'a','2'=>'b','3'=>'c','4'=>'d','5'=>'e','6'=>'f');

$t = array_diff_key($mainArray, $removeIndex);

print_r($t);
```

As @Elias pointed out you can use `array_flip` to change the values to keys in your `removeIndex` array.

Comment: That's why you may use [`array_flip()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Answer (score 1):

try [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function. This must work perfect.

```
unset($mainArray[1]);
```

Comment: `unset` _would_ require a loop, which the OP is trying to avoid